# How to migrate from ext4 to zfs root filesystem with separate ext4 boot partition?

Tags: ext4, chroot, zfs

I'm trying to change my root partition from ext4 to zfs (simple partition, without ZFS volume management functions) by moving all files in a live system (Ubtunu 14.04) from the ext4 partition to an external device, creating a ZFS pool on the partition and moving files back.

There're a lot of guides out there explaining how to setup OSs, including Ubuntu, on a root ZFS pool, but I didn't find one explaining the simple migration I want to do without setting up a ZFS boot partition/dataset as well (the most useful I found was http://blog.ls-al.com/ubuntu-on-a-zfs-root-file-system-for-ubuntu-14-04/). Of course it's possible to abstract the steps from such guides, but I'd rather have some little pointer from experts rather than doing a trial-error approach myself.

**General problems:** Currently I'm suffering for a lack of understanding how to tell my system to mount a ZFS partition under `/' at boot. Although it is not recommended I guess setting`mountpoint=legacy`and adding an entry in`/etc/fstab` (like I'd do after a migration to another filesystem type) should be sufficient, right?

**Actual problems:**

- If I create the pool with `zpool create /dev/sdaX`, I get the message `ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid of my root partition> doesn't exist`. When I create it with `zpool create /dev/disk/by-id/<id>` I get `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of`/dev/`when I run update-grub in chroot in live system. What Do I have to specify in`zpool create`?
- Do I have to setup the system in chroot from within the live system at all (import the pool, update initramfs)? I copied my files back to a dataset named `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu-1` and added `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu-1` to `/etc/fstab` (in that very dataset).

Running `mount -t zfs rpool/ROOT/ubuntu-1 /root && chroot /root zpool import rpool` in initramfs shell doesn't work because zfs module isn't loaded. `ubuntu-zfs` is installed and I used it for a data partition for a long time without trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel parameters `boot=zfs`, `bootfs` and `rpool` aren't set correctly by grub ("updates" from `ppa:zfs-native/grub` are for raring only) and have to be added to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to the `linux` statement(s) of your choice, see https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem for details.